# MythTV GUI problems

Tags: gui, resolution, mythtv

I'm using MythTV to watch TV on my ubuntu computer and I'm having a problem with the resolution.

It seems that the GUI resolution is matched with the channel resolution, so If I'm watching a HD channel, I get a nice GUI but If I'm watching a SD channel, then it's crap.

A couple of screenshots to show the difference:

High Definition Channel:

[image: High Definition Channel]

Standard Definition Channel:

[image]

I haven't found any similar issue in the internet and neither an option in the settings menu of MythTV (backend and frontend).

I have another small problem that you can see in the first screenshot, the channel name is cut (it shows "Telemadri" and the last letter is not completely shown). Anyone know how can I fix this too?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could be experiencing [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mythtv/+bug/684428) ("Horizontal picture shrink and lower third blurred on channel change"). If not, you should consider [filing a bug report yourself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

- Bugs against the mythtv package in Ubuntu are tracked at [bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mythtv](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mythtv). Make sure to
  thoroughly search them before reporting your own.

If this is the bug you're experiencing, you may want to [subscribe to it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering if you have tried modifying any of these Frontend parameters and if not they might be worth trying[image: Frontend.. Setup/Appearance]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this from the Mythtv menu. Utilities/Setup-Setup-TV Settings-Playback
. Try the various Zoom options, probably Full is the one you want to try.  Though I have it set for Auto Detect (default off) and SD and HD work fine. You probably also need to say which version of Ubuntu and Mythtv you are using.